# When the user agree and give my Facebook app permisions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I develop a Facebook application and I use PHP-sdk I use the algorithm described in the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) to allow user joining my app then I store his/her user_id in the database. My app uses publish_stream permissions so it publishes posts to the user's time line automatically.

I found that the application, always, does not able to publish posts for some of the registered users in the database (not all of them). I account this for they may be registered to the database before they give approval for the required permissions. The following is a **blue print** for the *code* that I use from the official documentation of Facebook api:

```
<?php  
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  );
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {
      try {
       /* $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];*/
     //Here I run the code to save.
         saveTheUserIdToRecordInTheDB($user_id);
       //hypothetical function to save

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

**My, main, question is**: If the user clicked on the login link, and then he/she does not continue for any reason (losing the internet connection, refusing giving the permissions to the app, etc), would it possible the hypothetical function *saveTheUserIdToRecordInTheDB()* to run and save that user's Facebook's ID to the database?

**Or** What's the explanation for there are some users are not posts publishable?

Comment: User can revoke the publish permission whenever they want

Comment: @FabioAntunes Yes I know, but I need to know when supposed, in the code logic, the user agree and give the permission?!